# What is the difference between dust bags for Festool vacuums which do, and don't, have the autoclean feature?

Tags: power-tools, dust-collection

I have a Festool CTM26E, without autoclean, and I'm trying to choose aftermarket dust bags.

Some of the bags I see on ebay say "Not suitable for CT standard version (without AC)" which is lifted directly from the description of the genuine Festool bag "Disposable bag ENS-CT 26 AC/5".

Festool have the "SELFCLEAN filter bag SC FIS-CT 26/5" which doesn't mention that restriction.

What's the actual difference between these bags?
What is it about the first that makes it unsuitable for a non-autoclean CT 26?
And what should I look for in an aftermarket bag to be sure that I'm getting a non autoclean compatible bag?